# Reverse DNS not working , not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)

Tags: centos, cpanel, vps, whm, reverse-dns

i have a vps with WHM installed, and now i try to add rDns , i was following this guide
https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Configure+Reverse+DNS+for+BIND+in+WHM

but it doesnt work..

my ip address is 192.99.175.224 , and the hostname is vps.indowebdeveloper.com,

I was try to add a dns zone on whm

```
IP : 192.99.175.224

Domain : 224.175.99.192.in-addr.arpa
```

And after i add it, i use edit dns zone to add PTR record on `224.175.99.192.in-addr.arpa`

Here is my configuration 
[image]

And after that, i try to use `host 192.99.175.224` on SSH i get

```
Host 224.175.99.192.in-addr.arpa. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

Am i missed something ? can anybody here help me out.. thankyou

Comment: http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Jeez, I really think se is becoming overspecialized.

Comment: Your hoster normally defines the reverse DNS records. You could ask them to add the `224` entry to the zone `175.99.192.in-addr.arpa`.

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me even though the nameservers and DNS records were setup correctly. Turned out that the domain name had previously had privacy service and on domain renewal the privacy service had not been renewed and so the ICANN administrative email was still set to the privacy service so that when ICANN domain confirmation email was sent out it was never received. The domain was then suspended without notice by the domain registrar, netfirms.com. Once I updated the administrative contact associated with the domain and confirmed the resulting ICANN email to confirm the domain's ownership, all worked.  I mightn't have found it for a while, but the support folks at rackspace.com suggested that somehow the domain might be suspended. netfirms support confirmed this. It is the domain owner's responsibility to keep admin contact info, read: email, up to date. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Solved my problem, thanks Joe.  Plus I got some before-and-after dig reports for my own archives, related to this.

Comment: This will solve my problem too. Useful answer.